How to lock the body in a mailto link
I am creating a customer referral experience, where a customer can click a "mailto" link to send a pre-written message to their friend:
Example:
href="mailto:?body=Here's a great site I found! Take a look! https://www.example.com"
Is there a way to "lock" the text in the body so the user can't edit it? We are a regulated industry and need to make sure all required language is included.
I have searched this site and google and have not found an answer. Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

No, a web page in a browser has no control over a user's email client.  You'll need to send the email from server-side code to have more control over it.

You can't do this the way you're thinking. Mailto links are opened by the email client, and while the body of the email can be prefilled, the user can freely edit it after that.
In order to send an email with fixed content, you'd need to set up a web form or similar, where the user could enter the email address to send to and a prefilled message would be sent.

Not possible. Not desirable.
Sending an email from my account with your words would be an horrendous security risk, no? What you're asking to do is something we actively work to disallow in all sectors.
What if you could send an email from my account to the finance department asking for an invoice to be paid? How much could you steal before we noticed? You could send anyone anything from my account - that would be terrifying.
No, what you're asking for is highly undesirable for everybody involved, and trying to do that with someone's account would very quickly lose you all your customers.
